# Windows 10 slow boot

Tags: windows-10, boot

Recently I found that my pc boots slowly, the symptom is:

1. motherboard BIOS logo screen appears (fast)
2. Windows 10 loading screen appears (fast)
3. Windows 10 loading spinning dots appears after 1 minute (**slow**)
4. Windows 10 loading spinning dots spins for less than 1 second (fast)
5. Windows 10 login screen appears (fast)

As you can see from the above sequence, the slowness happens between 2 and 3. The spinning dots used to appear together with the Windows 10 loading screen, however recently the spinning dots appears after the loading screen after some 1 minute.

The motherboard BIOS booting order settings have never been changed and the Windows 10 boot SSD has always been the first in the booting order so I doubt the booting slowness has anything to do with the motherboard BIOS. However, I updated the BIOS to the latest version anyways to see if it would help and it did not.

I am wondering if there is any software or Windows logging that can help triage this kind of issue?

**=== EDIT #1 ===**

I tested booting without some I/O devices and surprisingly I found booting without the Logitech Unify Receiver plugged into the USB hub of my monitor solved the problem albeit I only tried the booting couple of times.

**=== EDIT #2 ===**

**tl;dr**: problem solved after disconnecting the USB hub in my monitor to the PC.

More info in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1703409/135275).

Comment: More likely than not a maintenance task is occuring - likely `ChkDsk`, so check Event Viewer's log for `ChkDsk`. If `C:` is on a mechanical HDD, it's possible there's fragmentation of the MFT [Master File Table], but `ChkDsk` is far more likely. If you think it may be the latter, use `contig` or Power Defragmenter _(both are apart of Microsoft's SysInternals suite)_, as the MFT can only be defragged with a more advanced defragmenter, such as the aforementioned two.

Comment: @GJ you ought to add the fix as an answer.

Comment: @spikey_richie I am trying to verify a few more things before I put up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Load `msconfig`, and on the Boot tab, enable 'Boot log'. Reboot, and then go and review the log file `C:\Windows\ntbtlog.txt`

[image]

This will help inform you of what's causing the slowness.

Whilst you have msconfig open, you might as well check the number of processors isn't locked at 1, or a memory cap set.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the instructions, of which I have tried before posting this question. The boot log does not help as it only logs one timestamp at the very beginning of the logging session so I cannot tell the loading of which service causes the most time. In addition, I also tried disabling all non-Microsoft services during boot and it makes no difference,

Comment: You ought to add that detail to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out what causes the slowness in my situation: the USB hub in my monitor ([ASUS PB328Q](https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Commercial-Monitors/PB328Q/specifications/)).

I tried booting without connecting the monitor to the pc using a [USB Type-B cable](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1015191) and verified that the booting slowness indicated in the question is gone.

While it is good that I found the root cause of my problem, now I have significantly less USB ports I can use. So I did some research and here are some of my findings:

- both the USB Type-B port on the monitor and the USB Type-A port on my PC are USB 3 as indicated by the blue color, while the cable that comes with the monitor and that I have used for the connection is for USB 2 as indicated by the white color, I am not sure if this is causing trouble
- the USB hub is shown as "Generic USB Hub" with the latest Microsoft driver installed in Windows 10 Device Manager and I cannot find anything suspicious